# Finding value in array by string and returning another value in the result array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(1) "1234"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) "Bosch"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "8348"
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "Makita"
  }
}
```

Now, I want to search for `Makita` and get `8348` as a result. How would I do that?

Comment: you will have to do foreach on your array and check if the label matches the string you want to search. If it matches, return value key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_search function for this

```
$key = array_search('Makita', array_column($userdb, 'value'));
echo $userdb[$key]['label'];
```